# Store a for loop values into a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to store the results of a for loop in a list but I get a list for each value by adding the new value, I just want to print the list with all the values only once, this is an example:

```
xlist=[]
for i in range(10):
    x=(i+1)
    xlist.append(x)
    print (xlist)
```

output:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What I want:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Move your `print` statement out of the for loop.

Comment: `print(list(range(1,11)))`

Answer (score 1):

You want only:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    xlist.append(i)
print(xlist)
```

No need for another parameter X in your case.
The reason this happened was because you printed out the lost each iteration, and not only when it was ready.

Comment: You are right of course, but one step at a time :)